# How to empty (reset) in JavaScript an input type email after fill it with whitespaces (in.value="" does not work)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, user-controls

When fill it an input (`type="email"`) with **only** whitespaces and want to clean it (`value === ""`) with JavaScript it does not works. Consider the following code ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/1kj52asr/)):

```
<input type="email" id="myEmail" placeholder="Enter e-mail" autocomplete="off">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myEmail').value = '';">Try it</button>
```

But the same code with an input type `text` or `password` works! I'm testing in Chrome.

**EDIT:**
Yes, using `setAttribute` works. But if you do not want to change the input attribute, any solution?

Comment: You are trying to check if the user has used just whitespace?

Comment: Not. What you say I already know how to do. I'm just want to empty the input.

Comment: That's a really strange interaction, what you're doing works fine with input `type='text'`, but for some reason it glitches with `type='email'`

Comment: @csr-nontol the attribute is bound to the input. I am not sure what result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bibberty when working with JS there is difference. e.g. - the input is clean, - the user write some text, then: `in.value !== in.getAttribute("value")`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than set the `value` attribute directly, set the "value" attribute of your email input directly by doing the following:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Remove this:
  // document.getElementById("myEmail").value = "";

  // Replace with this:
  document.getElementById("myEmail").setAttribute("value", "");
})
```

```html
E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" placeholder="Enter e-mail" autocomplete="off">

<button id="btn">Try it</button>

<p>Click button to empty the email field. Notice that the placehold is visible after clicking, even when email field contains whitespaces.</p>
```

This method forces the browser to re-render the input field so that the value presented matches the attribute that is set (ie `""`).

Why you original method doesn't work; my understanding is that, internally the `value` DOM attribute of the email input type is "trimmed" meaning reading or setting of a value padded with whitespaces is not distinguished from the same value without whitespaces. Updating the value to `""` from `"    "` would therefore be considered an update of the "same value" and would be ignored.

Comment: Yes. It's works. But can you explain why this happens? It's possible to do without change the input attribute?

Comment: @csr-nontol just updated answer - hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, the input will be empty if only string.
Edited to reflect observation by Dacre. Setting input.value did not update the actual control.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let email = document.getElementById('myEmail');
    email.setAttribute('value', email.value.trim());
        
    console.log(email.value.length);
    
  });

});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="myEmail" placeholder="Enter e-mail" autocomplete="off">
<button >Try it</button>
```

Comment: @DacreDenny hmm, I am using Chrome when writing and testing. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @DacreDenny edited based on you observation. Correct. The input itself was not being cleared and needed a call to setAttribute instead. Great spot.